# compilation error while throwing exception?

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

What is wrong with this code?

```
public class Mocker<T extends Exception> {
    private void pleaseThrow(final Exception t) throws T{
        throw (T)t;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
            new Mocker<RuntimeException>().pleaseThrow(new SQLException());
        }
        catch (final SQLException e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

As in `pleaseThrow` method throws `SQLException` still it gives Compilation error.

Error :

```
Unreachable catch block for SQLException. This exception is never thrown from the try 
 statement body
```

Comment: What is the Error? I did not get  any exception in above code

Comment: @SubodhJoshi You asked an answer ;)

Comment: Consider what the compiler thinks `Mocker<RuntimeException>().pleaseThrow()` can throw.

Comment: @SubodhJoshi You should.

Comment: @JonSkeet RunTimeException and it wasn't expecting SQLException. Thnx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is because you are throwing a `RuntimeException`, but trying to catch `SQLException`.

In your method,

```
private void pleaseThrow(final Exception t) throws T{
    throw (T)t;
}
```

You are casting the argument `SQLException` in your case to `T` (which is `RuntimeException` in your case and throwing it.

So, the compiler is expecting a `RuntimeException` to be thrown and not `SQLException`.

Hope this is clear.

Comment: I wonder if the code would work if SQLException would extend a RuntimeException...

Comment: @Marwie, even then you should catch RuntimeException, not SQLException, but since RuntimeException is unchecked, the compiler would allow you.

Comment: Of course - it wouldn't make sense to do it otherwise. But would the catch get a casted exception? This is propably for another question to answer. This question just made me thinking about that.

Comment: No... If a parent exception is being thrown, you can try to catch any child exception without compiler errors. Because when I say my method would throw Exception, it could very well be IOException (or any other) too.

Answer (score 2):

you would be able to write this when your `pleaseThrow`method actually throws `SQLException`.

Currently what you are doing is just passing a object of type `SQlExcetion` as parameter to this  method.

Currently what Compiler observes is you are calling a method and it does not throw any SQLException , so compiler deems the catch clause as a problem and shows this compilation problem

Answer (score 2):

Your `pleaseThrow()` does not throw an `SQLException`. You have some choices: make your `catch` to catch a generic `Exception`

```
        catch (final Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

*or*  make `pleaseThrow(..)` actually throw an `SQLException`

```
    private void pleaseThrow(final Exception t) throws SQLException{
        throw (SQLException)t;
    }
```

*or* actually throw an `SQLException`

```
new Mocker<SQLException>().pleaseThrow(new SQLException());
```